# Combining multiple files of uncommon filetype into one

Tags: python, opencv

I've created a utility program for combining multiple .vec files into one. The program's main application is in training haar cascade classifiers in openCV ([details](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/user_guide/ug_traincascade.html)). This is my first open source contribution that other people may find useful and I would like to improve it if possible.

I'm mainly interested in feedback on the coding style, but any comments would be appreciated.

```
"""    
    To use the function:
    (1) Place all .vec files to be merged in a single directory (vec_directory).
    (2) Go to the bottom of this file and enter the vec_directory along with an output filename.
    (3) Navigate to this file in your CLI (terminal or cmd) and type "python mergevec.py".

    To test the output of the function:
    (1) Install openCV.
    (2) Navigate to the output file in your CLI (terminal or cmd).
    (2) Type "opencv_createsample -w img_width -h img_height -vec output_filename". 
        This should show the .vec files in sequence.

"""

import sys
import glob
import struct
import traceback

def exception_response(e):
    exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback = sys.exc_info()
    lines = traceback.format_exception(exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback)
    for line in lines:
        print(line)

def merge_vec_files(vec_directory, output_vec_file):
    """
    Iterates throught the .vec files in a directory and combines them. 

    (1) Iterates through files getting a count of the total images in the .vec files
    (2) checks that the image sizes in all files are the same

    The format of a .vec file is:

    4 bytes denoting number of total images (int)
    4 bytes denoting size of images (int)
    2 bytes denoting min value (short)
    2 bytes denoting max value (short)

    ex:     6400 0000 4605 0000 0000 0000

        hex     6400 0000   4605 0000       0000        0000
                # images    size of h * w       min     max
        dec         100         1350            0       0

    :type vec_directory: string
    :param vec_directory: Name of the directory containing .vec files to be combined. 
                Do not end with slash. Ex: '/Users/username/Documents/vec_files'

    :type output_vec_file: string
    :param output_vec_file: Name of aggregate .vec file for output. 
        Ex: '/Users/username/Documents/aggregate_vec_file.vec'

    """

    # Check that the .vec directory does not end in '/' and if it does, remove it.
    if vec_directory.endswith('/'):
        vec_directory = vec_directory[:-1]
    # Get .vec files
    files = glob.glob('{0}/*.vec'.format(vec_directory))

    # Check to make sure there are .vec files in the directory
    if len(files) <= 0:
        print('Vec files to be mereged could not be found from directory: {0}'.format(vec_directory))
        sys.exit(1)
    # Check to make sure there are more than one .vec files
    if len(files) == 1:
        print('Only 1 vec file was found in directory: {0}. Cannot merge a single file.'.format(vec_directory))
        sys.exit(1)


    # Get the value for the first image size
    prev_image_size = 0
    try:
        with open(files[0], 'rb') as vecfile:
            content = ''.join(vecfile.readlines())
            val = struct.unpack('<iihh', content[:12])
            prev_image_size = val[1]
    except IOError as e:
        print('An IO error occured while processing the file: {0}'.format(f))
        exception_response(e)


    # Get the total number of images
    total_num_images = 0
    for f in files:
        try:
            with open(f, 'rb') as vecfile:  
                content = ''.join(vecfile.readlines())
                val = struct.unpack('<iihh', content[:12])
                num_images = val[0]
                image_size = val[1]
                if image_size != prev_image_size:
                    print('The image sizes in the .vec files differ. These values must be the same.')
                    print('The image size of file {0}: {1}'.format(f, image_size))
                    print('The image size of previous files: {0}'.format(prev_image_size))
                    sys.exit(1)

                total_num_images += num_images
        except IOError as e:
            print('An IO error occured while processing the file: {0}'.format(f))
            exception_response(e)


    # Iterate through the .vec files, writing their data (not the header) to the output file
    # '<iihh' means 'little endian, int, int, short, short'
    header = struct.pack('<iihh', total_num_images, image_size, 0, 0)
    try:
        with open(output_vec_file, 'wb') as outputfile:
            outputfile.write(header)

            for f in files:
                with open(f, 'rb') as vecfile:
                    content = ''.join(vecfile.readlines())
                    data = content[12:]
                    outputfile.write(data)
    except Exception as e:
        exception_response(e)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # fill in the directory name and the output filename below
    vec_directory =             # ex: '/Users/user_name/vec'
    output_filename =           # ex: '/Users/user_name/aggregate_vec.vec'
    merge_vec_files(vec_directory, output_filename)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an expert in Python, but I think you can improve it in some ways:

- Instead of making the user write down the names at the end of the file, you could make the script take them from the console using (after checking they exist)

  ```
  vec_directory = sys.argv[1]

  output_filename = sys.argv[2]
  ```
- Maybe instead of using prints and then exiting with a 1, you can use

  ```
  system.exit("Error message")
  ```